# How can I take input from something the Console has printed in Python?

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter, console

I am building an `Encrypter/Decrypter` and I already got the backend working. To `encrypt or decrypt a file` you need to `input the name and the extension` (`Example: Image.png`).

If the file name you input on it doesn't exist or has a typo, the console prints:

> ```
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> ```

proceeded with your input text.

What I want to be able to do is like an If(the console prints that error message), then display a text that says `"No file found. Please check your directory or your spelling"` using `Tkinter`.

Please help me so I can finish the project.

Comment: Wheres the code?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to include this in your code

```
try:
    #open file
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("No file found. Please check your directory or your spelling")
```

and that should work